# Does Intune require paid "Apple Developer Program" in order to add Apple devices?

Tags: intune, apple

I'm trying to add Apple devices to InTune, following Microsoft's steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/apple-mdm-push-certificate-get .

Do I need to be part of Apple's paid "Apple Developer Program" in order to do this?